# scaling symfony/mongo application

Tags: mongodb, symfony, rabbitmq, scaling

Thanks for reading
I need a technical expertise regarding scaling our actual stack.

- main application coded with php (symfony 3)
- rabbit mq as a backend system to avoid latency (messages are handled by php cli scripts, symfony again)
- mongo db
- 1 main server that hosts everything

My app is something similar to mailchimp, sendInblue, it's an email automation tool.

- The client can upload his own contacts database in our system (api)
- The client can configure an email to be sent to a particular time.
- The client can define some rule to determine wether or not that email should be send to a particular contact.

It works well with 4 millions contacts, we send 150 000 emails per day.

Our activity is growing very fast, and we expect to send **3M** emails per day, with contact databases of **200M** documents.

- can I handle billions rows of documents with doctrine + mongodb ?
- which performances problems can I expect to face ?
- I know I can distribute datasets across multiple systems with sharding, is there any others methods ?
- In this case of situation, does the php code need to be (completely?) refactored for scaling ?
- Let's say I ask my admin sys to upgrade the system to handle billions rows, do I need to think about that in my code ?

Now let's talk about something more specific, how to process the contacts to send the email ?
My actual implementation is this one :

- I have 4 millions clients to evaluate between 9am and 21pm
- a cron dispatch 6000 contacts ids to rabbit mq every minute
- a php process (symfony console script) is always running and wait to process the new contact id

  - get the contact document from mongodb
  - evaluate the rules
  - send the email if the rules are true

I use supervisorD to manage an always running php cli script.
Because it is not fast enough, I put 6 running process in supervisord.

But I can not put 60 parallels php process to go 10 times faster right ?
How do you scale such a system ?
Would you have this implemented in a different way, if so how ?

And last but big question, considering all of that, can I expect benefits moving to a nodejs stack ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124867/where-should-i-ask-software-architecture-design-questions